# Fast matrix multiplication of all combinations of matrix pairs in two lists

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say we are given two lists of `NxN` matrices (`L1` with `M1` matrices, `L2` with `M2` matrices), and we would like to find an efficient way to multiply all the possible `M1*M2` pairs of matrices.

**Simple example:** Given `L1 = [a1, a2, a3]` and `L2 = [b1, b2]` as input, we want to get `[a1.b1, a1.b2, a2.b1, a2.b2, a3.b1, a3.b2]`, where `.` stands for numpy's `dot()`.

Actually, let's make this better right away: the inputs should be two numpy arrays with shape `(M1, N, N)` and `(M2, N, N)`; the output should be of shape `(M1*M2, N, N)`.

**Questions:**

1. How can this be done efficiently with numpy and no loops? I've been trying with no success.
2. How can we extend this such that besides multiplying together all pairs we also add a fixed `NxN` matrix `X` to each product result every time.

*Starting code:*

```
import numpy as np
N  = 2
M1 = 3
M2 = 2
L1 = np.random.randn(M1, N, N)
L2 = np.random.randn(M2, N, N)
X  = np.random.randn(N, N)
```

Comment: With broadcasting we can multiply a (m1,1,n,n) with a (1,m2,n,n) to produce a (m1,m2,n,n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
import numpy as np

N  = 2
M1 = 3
M2 = 2
L1 = np.random.randn(M1, N, N)
L2 = np.random.randn(M2, N, N)

arr = np.dot(L1,L2).reshape(M1*M2,N,N)
arr = np.stack(arr, axis = 1).reshape(M1*M2,N,N)

print(arr.shape)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
(6, 2, 2)
[[[-0.23801453  0.28045455]
  [-0.20878195  0.93019629]]

 [[ 0.31130404  2.03630303]
  [-0.41401161 -0.70762532]]

 [[ 2.66698736  0.34818929]
  [ 0.17368564 -0.82483313]]

 [[-0.45976939  0.25588863]
  [-1.1408594   0.74448629]]

 [[-1.98923364  1.49183873]
  [ 0.48897251 -0.46352228]]

 [[ 1.38875825 -0.21409729]
  [ 1.00406231 -0.65810354]]]
```

Comment: Ya, i didn't read the question properly but this time i did all this without any loop.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you want for question 2?

Comment: For your next question, you just simply add the array. Let's say that the array you want to add is c, simply add it to arr by arr+c and all will be done by numpy's broadcasting feature

Comment: Great, thanks. I edited your answer. Hopefully will be visible soon.